# Regex search in text files using Windows Grep

Tags: regex

this is driving me crazy. 
How do I write a regular expression to determine higher value than 0.5 in a search string please?

For example:
sd=0.398
sd= is the mandatory text in text document I am searching for using Windows Grep and this string is always 4 digits long after decimal point.

and I would like to search for entries higher than 0.5

Those can be:
0.501
1.567
12.567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this.

```
sd=[0-9]+\.[5-9][0-9]*
```

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/dF8nC3/1

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression should match `sd=` followed by a decimal number with exactly three digits after the decimal (where the first digit after the decimal is 5+).

`sd=[0-9]+\.[5-9][0-9][0-9]`